# Different behaviour of requests package in two "identical" python environments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, centos

I have two virtual machines (VMs) that ran a Python 2.7 in Centos 5.9. Since Centos 5.9 comes with Python 2.4 we had to manually build and compile Python 2.7. Both VMs were setup in different periods with different procedures, since the first one was setup 3 years ago with Python 2.7.11 while the second one was setup a day ago with Python 2.7.17. Both of them have the same version of requests package (2.9.1).

The problem is that when I ran the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from asterisk.agi import *
import requests

url_format = 'http://app.domain.com/api/v1/object/search?id={}'
id = 561089
response = requests.get(url_format.format(id))
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
```

I get the following error in the newer VM (Python 2.7.17):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 800, in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

While I don't get an error on the former VM but the actual json object:

```
{u'uri': u'user.name@app.domain.com', u'domain': u'app.domain.com', u'user': u'user.name'}
```

The strange thing is that looking at the value of `response.text` I get me the same result on both setups:

```
// first
u'{"uri": "user.name@app.domain.com", "domain": "app.domain.com", "user": "user.name"}'

// second
u'{"uri": "user.name@app.domain.com", "domain": "app.domain.com", "user": "user.name"}'
```

Running the following code:
    import json
    json.loads(r.content)

Results in the following:

```
// first
{u'uri': u'user.name@app.domain.com', u'domain': u'app.domain.com', user': u'user.name'}

// second
{u'u\x00r': u's\x00e\x00b\x00a\x00s\x00t\x00i\x00', u'd\x00o\x00m\x00': u'2\x000\x009\x00.\x001\x003\x000\x00', u's\x00e\x00c\x00o\x00n\x00d\x00': u's\x00e\x00b\x00a\x00s\x00t\x00i\x00a\x00n\x00.\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00o\x00@\x00c\x00h\x00i'}
Note: In all cases but this last one, the actual characters were replaced.
```

If both are Python 2.7, both have the same version of the requests package and both of them are receiving the exact same text from the server, how is it that I am getting an error in the second VM? Do I have to compile differently Python?

**How I compiled Python 2.7.17 in the second VM**

I cannot tell you how the Python 2.7.11 was compiled in the first VM but the Python 2.7.17 was compiled in the following way:

Download and install OpenSSL

```
cd /tmp 
curl http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz | tar zxvf - 
cd openssl-1.0.2.h 
./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ 
make && make install
```

Set up some environment variables

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/openssl"
```

Download and install Python 2.7.17

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.17/Python-2.7.17.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.17.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.17
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared
make && make altinstall
```

Finally I had to add `/usr/local/lib/` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue of some kind. On your second machine, all those extra null bytes from `r.content` indicates it was UTF-16 encoded, rather than UTF-8.

Comment: @S.Bender Speaking as someone who also has a few stray CentOS 5 boxes hanging around, Python 2's end-of-life is probably the least of the OP's problems :)

Comment: @chepner, that is correct. I could not care less about the version of Python for now, same as the Centos version. Once I manage to get it running I will deal that later.

Comment: @chepner, why would one machine encode it in UTF-16 and the other in UTF-8? What can I do to make it the same as the other?

Comment: Sorry, no idea; just an observation I had.